# Error while updating redux state using immutability-helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I'm trying to set one exact value, stored in array which is stored in my state object, all in redux.

```
const initialState = {
    orderedItems: [
    {item:"1Reco",price:"12",amount:1},
    {item:"2Reco",price:"12",amount:1},
    ],
    fullPrice: 0,
    windowWidth: 1418,
    language: "en"
};
```

Let's say 2Reco amount to 2.
I have been trying to use update and $set like that:

```
let newamount = state.orderedItems[i].amount+1;
return update(state, { 
    orderedItems: { 
        [i]: {
            amount: {$set:newamount}
      }
    },fullPrice: newPrice
  });
```

But when this update is firing,im getting "Error: update(): You provided an invalid spec to update()." back, and I don't know why. I have seen simillar solutions here on stack earlier, and they don't seem to work for me. When console logging, newamount shows a number 2, so exactly what I want to set in that place. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the state directly. In a general scenario in Redux you must `... operator`. Something like this:

For

```
orderedItems: [
  {item:"1Reco",price:"12",amount:1},
  {item:"2Reco",price:"12",amount:1},
],
```

Try

```
const updatedOrderedItems = orderedItems.map(obj=>{
                if(obj.item==="2Reco"){
                    obj.amount=obj.amount+1;
                    return obj; 
                }
                return obj;
});
```

Now your updatedOrderedItems contains the updated array of object containing the amount 2 for second object.

Then you can update global state in redux from your reducer function as follows:

```
return{
  ...state,
    orderedItems: updatedOrderedItems 
    fullPrice: 0,
    windowWidth: 1418,
    language: "en"
   
}
```

Comment: I was sure update was already doing that, not gonna lie, as earlier i have been mutating them all for example for reservations, setting price and stuff, but had problems modifying amount variable. So as I see, mapping all of orderedItems made the trick, will definitly use it more in the future, working like a bless. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a directly answer to your question, I would *strongly* recommend using Immer to write immutable updates instead of the `immutability-helper` library:

https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

The code will be much simpler.

In addition, [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) already uses Immer internally, and you should be using Redux Toolkit to write your Redux logic.